# regular expression not working: repeated strings of digits

Tags: c#, regex, winforms

I was trying to create a regular expression to find repeated strings of digits.
eg:

```
1     -not matching
11    -matching
122   -matching
1234  -not matching
```

what i used is `\d+`. Tutorial are telling

> the "+" is similar to "*", except it requires at least one repetition.

But when i tried it is matching with any number. Any idea why?

**Update**
The tutorial i tried : http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/9099/The-Minute-Regex-Tutorial

Comment: Can you link the tutorial which said so ?

Comment: i have added the link to tutorial in question

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The repetition constructs in Regular Expressions, `+`, `*`, `{x}`, do not repeat "what you found the first time around", they repeat "the pattern that finds things".

So this:

```
\d+
```

Will not find one digit, then match a sequence *of that digit*, instead it will first find one digit, then try to find another digit, then another, etc.

If you want it to repeat "what it found" you have to explicitly say so:

```
(\d)\1+
```

The `\1` here says "I will match whatever is in the first group again", this regular expression should match sequences *of the same digit*, instead of sequences *of digits*.

Answer (score 2):

```
^\d*(\d)\1+\d*$
```

You can use this.See demo.`\d+` would match any intergers `1 or more time`.You need to use `\1` to find repeated digits.

https://regex101.com/r/hI0qP0/4

Answer (score 2):

It works properly. `\d+` is not a repetition of a specific digit, it is a repetition of one or more `\d`. `\d+` will match `1` (one or more digit), `12` (one or more digit), `122` (one or more digit)... you see the idea. If you want to see two or more repetitions, you'd need to say `\d\d+` or `\d{2,}` - but this, too, says that you want two or more digits, not two or more of a same digit. To say that, you need backreferences: `(\d)\1+` is two or more of a same digit: a digit we remember, then one or more of that remembered thing.